# How to use a 3rd party iOS Framework in a Nativescript App

Tags: ios, nativescript

I need the functionality of a 3rd party iOS Framework. (Let's call it My-Example.framework) in my Nativescript-Angular project.

This Framework has the following structure:

```
My-Example.framework
|-Assets
|-Headers
| |-Example-Swift.h
| |-Example.h
|-Info.plist
|-Modules
  |-Example.swiftmodule
  | |-arm64.swiftdoc
  | |-arg64.swiftmodule
  | |-x86_64.swiftdoc
  | |-x86_64.swiftmodule
  |-module.modulemap
```

I have read the docs:
https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/plugins/Use-Native-iOS-Libraries

But I still have no idea how to use this framework in my project.

Any suggestions? Links?

Comment: Place the framework file in the `platforms/ios` folder of your plugin, all the apis exposed by the framework should be accessible at run time. May I ask what else you do not exactly understand?

Comment: Thats the information I needed. In docs it says something about creating cocoapods/plugins etc.
I know that I can access native functionality with {N} but I didn't know how this works with a external custom ios framework.

Will give your solution a try.

Comment: Whatever I have shared, it's from [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/plugins/Use-Native-iOS-Libraries#shared-frameworks) only. Perhaps you just had to read it fully.

Comment: Oh wait.

platforms/ios is generated.
So any manual changes would be overwritten/reset when I remove/add platform.

Any other ways to solve this?

Comment: Not the `platforms/ios` in your plugin. The one in your project is auto generated.

Comment: I dont have a plugin yet.

Comment: No I meant `platforms/ios` within your plugin. The docs you ad linked in your question is about building plugin. But if you want to just access the apis in your project, yes `App_Resources/iOS` might work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194099/discussion-between-naxos84-and-manoj).